# Xpath returns matched string and words around it

Tags: php, xpath

Suppose I have

```
<body>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph, there are three paragraphs in this page</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Just another paragraph. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
</body>
```

I'd like to find all words that matches 'paragraph' and surround it with 4 words before and after matched word. The list of result would be like:

- This is a **paragraph.**
- This is another **paragraph**, there are three
  paragraphs...
- ...paragraph, there are three **paragraphs** in this page.
- ...sit amet. Just another **paragraphs**. Ut enim ad
  minim...

I'm new to xpath so the best that I can do is this code which is going to get all text nodes that contains 'paragraph'

```
$test = $xml->xpath('//body//*[text()[contains(.,"paragraph")]]');
```

resulting:

- This is a paragraph
- This is another paragraph, there are three paragraphs in this page
- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Just another paragraph. Ut enim ad minim
  veniam.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, What do you want to be produced? I couldn't understand what must be produced. What do the elipsis in the wanted result mean? Please, explain.

Comment: He's basically looking for a list of all occurrences of a given word ('paragraph' in the example above), and wants to display the four words found on either side of it, presumably to offer some clues as to the context in which the word is used in each case. I'd agree with Michael, this is nearly impossible with just XPath.

Comment: @Flynn1179: Probably can be done with XPath 2.0. I have long ago had a concordance generator -- in XSLT 2.0 (http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200511/msg00190.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you mention PHP suggests you are probably looking for an XPath 1.0 solution.

Several problems here:

- XPath 1.0 doesn't have good text processing capabilities, and can't
  make up for them with user-defined functions

  XPath (1.0 or 2.0) can't create new nodes and therefore has
  difficulty returning structured results.

If you're stuck with PHP, and therefore with XPath 1.0, I think I would be content to return the matching text nodes to the PHP application and then do the rest of the processing in PHP.

The alternative would be to use XSLT: in XSLT 1.0 it's still a challenge, but with the aid of recursive templates it's certainly possible.

Comment: +1. You are right, I did the rest of the process in PHP. Dind't think of it before. Thanks alot!